In .NET Microsoft.Extensions.Logging infrastructure should I use event IDs or are names enough
So far I never bothered with event ID and just set it to 0. Only utilising event name in log explorer/aggregator/analyser tools. Or is this what everybody does? And if so is 0 the preferred value or should another value be used? I saw LoggerMessageAttribute.EventId defaults to -1, but then seems to generate a random value.
If I should use event IDs, what is the best practice for managing event IDs when defining log messages?
By manage I mean keep them unique and also allow looking up what event id is used where. Something easily integrateable with LoggerMessageAttribute CodeGen. Also should an event ID be unique across all events or just within a category?
Simplest solution I came up with was using an enum. But that does lead to some redundancy with the name, because it is already inferred from the method (when using LoggerMessageAttribute).
Edit: In .NET Microsoft.Extensions.Logging the EventId is used as an identifier for Events (OriginalFormat could also be used). The EventId struct allows to define EventId.Name (string) and/or EventId.Id (int32) as an identifier. The question is about best practices about these two options. And the relevance of EventId.Id, because I would argue it is harder to manage and keep unique an int32 than a string identifier.
Edit2: FYI, if the EventId-Property on the LoggerMessageAttribute is omitted, the code generators uses a hash of the EventName-Property (when omitted equal to the method name) to a somewhat unique int32 id using this as the event id: LoggerMessageGenerator.Parser.cs - Line 908

In short: Yes, you should have unique id for each log row.
Long answer needs bit reflection and understanding.
Why are you writing a log?
If you are trying to trace down exact moment and pinpoint which event created that log when something did happen then you need unique id. In case of LoggerMessageAttribute that would be the EventId.
LoggerMessageAttribute has four properties that will deliver content information:

EventId, The log event Id
EventName, the logging event name for the logging method
LogLevel, The log level (Information, Warning, etc.)
Message, Format string of the log message.

See MS Learn about LoggerMessageAttribute and the source code from GitHub.
Why you are logging is the important question. If you are logging to find errors and unexpected events then you should definitely use EventId to define exact situation where that happened. Sadly EvenId is just Int32. Using some other logging frameworks you can give GUID as an EventId that would be globally unique but int32 is just locally unique. Also tinkering with numbers might create clashes within the system but that is part of another discussion.
If all log that is written is just information then it really doesn't matter. So, there is a slight chance to argue that you don't need to give EventId. But why would you write just information log but not errors?
